# Link Tables and Dynamically Update in Excel

Tags: excel

I have two Excel worksheets. Worksheet A has a table that needs to be populated by the contents of the table in worksheet B. The number of rows in worksheet B's table can change and the table in worksheet A needs to dynamically grow or shrink according to the other table's state.

Linking with the paste special tool only seems to link the first row. If another row is added in worksheet B, that change is not reflected in worksheet A.

Answer (score 0):

Use table format and Pivot Tables.

Use the Pivot Table to show the information in a very friendly way, connect this pivot table to the table where your data is. Here is a graphical explanation http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-reasons-to-use-excels-table-object/#.

Comment: I don't see how this would accomplish what I'm trying to. You cannot add or remove rows/cols to a pivot table so it can't grow or shrink.